# Powerpoint 2010 -- the line object appears as an arrow

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In my Powerpoint 2010, the line object appears as an arrow. I think this was software glitch.  Any fixes?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your problem? As it is we can't even begin to imagine what the problem actually is.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the arrow object selected rather than the plain line object?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the Line object - Then properties.
2. Choose the `Line Style` option, if it hasn't already been selected on the dialog that appears.
3. On the `Begin Type` and `End Type` drop-down menus check if an arrow head has been selected.

You should not have to go through the above steps if you're simply creating a line object, but something might be causing PowerPoint to do this.